# Display Text In Android. Shows Error

Tags: android

```
    <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Welcome" />
```

I Have Use This Code To Display Text In Android. But It Shows An Error . How Can I Solve This

Comment: It is impossible to say from the information you have provided. Please describe the error (or better) post the error logs.

Comment: whats the error. post complete error.

Comment: always give complete information of question so any one can under stand and help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you declare welcome string in string.xml. Don't use Capital letters like `@string/Welcome` in string.xml. Use `@string/welcome`.